# Help selecting a Mosfet/driver for 300vdc 3amp continuous on Arduino

Tags: mosfet, driver

The title spells it out mostly. Actual voltage will be from 15-240vdc max, load will be 1-3amp max, the mosfet will connect a resistive load. The circuit may be on for 10-30 hours at a time, 6-8 times per year.

The Arduino will want a 5v logic level gate. I am not sure, but I think it needs to be oversized to 300-400v 5amp rating? to reduce overheating. I can run a fan/heatsink/compound if needed.

The project I want to do has been done by many people in a manual archaic scenario, and a few commercial companies have automated using a complex circuit.

I have looked on Digikey, but honestly I am fuzzy on Mosfet ratings and 240vdc is extremely dangerous so I want to get it right the first time.

I also need suggestions as to driver selection, or need for diodes or protective addons between the driver/fet.

I have done a lot of preliminary research on this project, and it is probably above my current experience level, but this will be a learning experience that I embrace to take me to the next level.

My experience: I have 20 years of constant *basic* experience in electronics, I have a few occasional intermediate projects I have done, building or repairing things using high level guidance I find online. I am not very good on circuit design, I carry a few resistors and diodes around in my tool bag, I have replaced CAPs/FETs on a few stereo amps before, but it is easy to match a part number and suck some solder. I understand ohms law, and can read simple circuit diagrams. My profession is in the IT field, and I was taught to build houses and pull engines by the time I was 12- jack of a few trades.

I humbly offer my thanks to anyone that is willing to give me instruction.

Comment: "...controlled resistive load that I wish to **step down**" - what do you mean by 'step down', and how do you intend to do it?

Comment: You really should draw a circuit of what you're planning to do. What is a "controlled resistive load"? How do you want to "step the voltage down"?

Comment: My ramblings seem to throw people off, so I have removed that in hopes of concentrating on the primary topic. I have a diagram, but I suspect that will to lead to more wandering off topic.

Comment: *"Help selecting a ..."* We don't do that here.

Comment: Unfortunately digikey has nothing under 10v gate. I found TSM70NB1R4CP at Mouser that has 2-4v gate, 700v/3amp drain, 1.1ohm Drain-Source Resistance. Would this be safe to move 240vdc/3amp?

Comment: what a friendly place to hang out

Answer (score 1):

Your safest bet will probably be an isolated SSR. I would not recommend building your own switching circuit for that kind of voltage/power if you can avoid it.

I only googled for a minute, but it looks like you've got plenty of options, for example: http://www.mouser.com/catalog/645/usd/1929.pdf

These SSRs don't draw much power so you should be able to drive them directly from the Arduino pins. If you're sure your load is resistive, then you won't need any other protective components.

If the device you're controlling needs safety cutoffs, I would recommend setting that up with a second SSR or relay, so that any one device failing can't result in your load getting stuck on.